# How can I make it so only members with a specific role can execute a command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My question may seem common, but this time there's a twist. I need it to require a role AND one of the specific roles instead of just one of the few roles. Here's the code that I tried that didn't work

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Buffalo Bills")
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach", "Assistant Coach")
```

then from there, the rest of my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's one way you could do it. Using [`@commands.has_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role) and [`@commands.has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role), you can ensure that the user has one specific role as well as one of the roles given.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Must Have Role')
@commands.has_any_role('Role One', 'Role Two')
async def role_test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hey this worked") 
# This would only send if the user has 'Must Have Role' and either 'Role One' or 'Role Two'
```

[image: Working Image]

Comment: Alright, and if they don't have the role how would I make an error message?

Comment: @TooHard you can do something like [this](https://pastebin.com/tY2iiZgf).